# How to insert into a SQL Server CE database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-ce

I am trying to execute an insert into command for a SQL Server CE database, the one that comes with the starter asp.net website. I'm trying to keep the code dynamic so I can use this as a DB management page for all the tables in this DB. I keep getting

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

I was trying to do it with just a long string as the query but that didn't work either. What am I missing/doing wrong?

```
        SqlCeCommand Sqlcmd = new SqlCeCommand(); 
        Sqlcmd.Connection = db.Connection as SqlCeConnection; 

        var Cols = "";

        foreach (var column in Columns)
        {
            Sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue('@'+column, Request.Form[column]);
            Cols += column + ",";
            insertValues += '@' + it + ","; 
        }

        Cols = Cols.Substring(0, Cols.Length - 1);
        insertValues = insertValues.Substring(0, insertValues.Length - 1);

        Sqlcmd.CommandText =
          "INSERT INTO " + table + "("+Cols+") " +
          "VALUES ("+insertValues+")";

        Sqlcmd.Prepare();
        Sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What is the value of the `InnerException` of the exception? Use a `catch` block, and wrap your DB connection in a `using` statement.

Comment: And what is the actual command text?

Comment: Thanks Dai, I was able to dig and find the problem by using a catch and examining the error in Visual Studio. The problem was that I had a foreign key set on the postID and I was entering test data not thinking about it. So I changed the postID to a valid postID and now it works. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please open your connection and add using statements around your command and connection objects to ensure they are disposed.  Don't forget to close your connection.  Here's the [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.prepare(v=vs.100).aspx) MSDN provides.

Comment: Thanks, I will make sure to change that.